# Where is "Wednesday" pronounced "Wedinzday"?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

I recently heard a BBC radio announcer pronounce "Wednesday" in a peculiar way. The 'd' wasn't dropped, resulting in something like "Wedinzday" (`wɛdnzde`).

I've read some Scottish dialects use this pronunciation. Is it class- or region-based? Something from RP or "broadcaster English"? Also, it doesn't appear that other words containing "dn" are affected (e.g. *madness*, *midnight*, etc.), so is this just a phonological anomaly?

Comment: Glaswegians I know -- and no one else -- pronounce the D in Wednesday.

Comment: @JAM Thanks. That led me to information about the Standard Scottish English pronunciations. Feel free to make this an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @JAM, Zairja: I don't think it's at all "standard", even for Scottish speakers. I suspect it's largely a form of "hypercorrection" that's maybe higher among Scots because they tend to enunciate everything a bit more clearly than the UK average.

Comment: @Zairja, why not answer your own question -- I didn't say enough for an answer.

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wednesday) has IPA + audio clips. (TIL that American slang for Wednesday is apparently "Humpday".)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Scots […] tend to enunciate everything a bit more clearly than the UK average".That's contrary to the [stereotype](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXGP4Sez_Us&feature=player_detailpage#t=15s).

Comment: I can confirm as a Glaswegian living in Edinburgh that "Wedenzday" is what I would consider standard pronunciation and would think dropping the "d" quite strange.  It is closer to the root of "Wodin's day" but I have no idea whether it kept this pronunciation locally or has later moved to this.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: There are conflicting stereotypes involved - for example, [Rab C. Nesbitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rab_C._Nesbitt) wouldn't get a job reading the BBC news, but Kirsty Young and others have done well there. And I believe many UK-based call centres use Scots **because** they tend to speak clearly (perhaps because they wouldn't be so easily understood by us Sassenachs if they spoke more casually, and they need the jobs! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree that there may be a hyper-enunciated strand of Scottish speech and it's a product of colonial oppression.

Comment: @neil, it is actually not closer to the historical form. The Old English genitive of _Wōden_ was _Wōdnes_, and the day was known as _Wōdnesdæġ_. The form _Wodin’s_ is a modern invention, formed regularly in Modern English by adding the clitic _’s_ to the name, different to the actual genitive case used in Old English. So the Weegie /wɛdɪnzde/ is more likely a recent thing. ‘Wednesday’ is (as far as I can think) the only word that contains /dnzd/ in English, and the most obvious ways to get past this is simplification (/nzd/ as most places) and epenthesis (/dənzd/ or /dnəzd/ as in Glasgow).

Comment: I'm going to go with @JanusBahsJacquet's explanation. I think the fact that the d isn't pronounced is a simplification that can be attributed to the fact that pronouncing it sounds completely foreign to the English speakers, seeing as there are no similar words in the language. As a foreigner who's concerned with speaking the best English possible, I tend to pronounce the d, albeit very softly. Moreover, I think the d keeps the sound of the e in Wed- similar to the one in `bed`, rather than the one in `when`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My parents are both from Northern Britain, my mother from Newcastle upon Tyne and my father from Glasgow. They both say "Wed'nzday". By contrast, I was brought up and live in the South-west of England, where the local pronunciation is "Wenzday"

Comment: Yes, Suke is correct, the "d" is pronounced in my part of England (around Newcastle-upon-Tyne). This area uses many dialectal features, in terms of both pronunciation and vocabulary, that many people would regard as purely "Scottish".

Comment: @GeordieG My Northern Irish accent keeps it, though there's a similarity between us and the Scottish too. I don't think it's restricted to the North of the Pretanic Isles, though; I'm pretty sure it can be found elsewhere, too.

Comment: My own pronunciation *wɛdənzdi* comes from East Yorkshire where it is, or was, common

Answer (score 1):

Indian speakers also pronounce the "d" in Wednesday. I've heard both wɛdnzde and wɛnzde.